# Is there any way to add more colors to Log4j2's output via log4j2.xml?

Tags: log4j2

I know that I can already specify ANSI colors via [{style}](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html), which as a limited set of supported colors:

> The color names are ANSI names defined in the [AnsiEscape](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/AnsiEscape.html) class.

I would like to add additional colors that are normally available at my Linux shell to the live terminal console via log4j2.xml. Is there any way to output additional color explicitly, possibly with RGB or hex, by modifying only log4j2.xml?

I'm not concerned with portability. I tried using `\e[1;34m` and `\e[31m`, but the escape sequence doesn't pass through to the output.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was introduced in version `2.18.0` (cf. [LOG4J2-3538](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3538)): you can use the specifiers `#RRGGBB`, `FG_#RRGGBB` or `BG_#RRGGBB` in both the `%style` and `%highlight` patterns (cf. [documentation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3538)).

E.g.:

```
%style{Hello world!}{#abcdef}
```